# Socket.IO & Express alternative for C#?

Tags: c#, express, socket.io, webserver

I'm looking to see if it's possible to create an application using C# that creates a local web server and allows me to pass information from the server, to the client website.

I've been using Node.js with Express to create a local web server and then using Socket.io to pass information through to the client, to display in realtime with Javascript. Only issue is I'm more comfortable with C# and I'd like to distribute this application, with Node Modules and Electron the app is clocking in at around 150MB, it's also many files and folders as opposed to just a .exe

Details of Application:

- Reads data from log files
- Decodes Json inside files
- Sends specific data to website
- Client receives data and displays

I've managed to get halfway there by using HttpListener, but from what I understand I cant send data to it? So I figured I could edit the html before I sent it and have yet to setup the FindDivByID method

**TLDR; Is there a way to create a Local Web Server (Application) that is able to send data to the Client Website.**

EDIT: Thanks for the suggestion, though I'm hoping to keep it all down to one distributable application, that reads the data from the local PC, creates the web server and sends to the clients

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you wanna go full C#, I'd recommend SignalR, very solid

https://www.asp.net/signalr

Alternatively, you could keep your Socket.IO server in Node.JS and use this Socket.IO C# client library to interface with it (although I never really did tried)

https://github.com/Quobject/SocketIoClientDotNet